# How to change value of an item of a collection

Tags: vba, excel, collections

With this code (in excel-vba) I add to a collection a number of items depending on an array.
I use the value of the array as key and the string "NULL" as value for each item added.

```
Dim Coll As New collection
Dim myArr()

Set Coll = New collection
myArr() = Array("String1", "String2", "String3")

For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
    Coll.Add "NULL", myArr(i)
Next i
```

Now, if I want to change the value of an item, identifying it by the key, I must remove the item and then add an item with same key or is it possible to change the item value?

This below is the only way?

```
Coll.Remove "String1"
Coll.Add "myString", "String1"
```

Or is there something like: (I know that doesn't work)

```
Coll("String1") = "myString"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `Dictionary` (from the scripting library) instead?

Comment: AFAIK and as what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx) say, that is the only way. The Mug is correct, use a dictionary instead. If you decide to take that route, [check this out.](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Comment: You can't do that with collection.

Comment: Ok, only another question: is there any contraindication for using dictionary instead of collection?

Comment: Yes. This will help you. I found it the other day: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8

Answer (score 15):

You can also write a (public) function to make updates to a collection.

```vb
public function updateCollectionWithStringValue(coll as Collection, key as string, value as string) as collection
    coll.remove key
    coll.add value, key
    set updateCollectionWithStringValue = coll
end function
```

You can invoke this function by:

```vb
set coll = updateCollectionWithStringValue(coll, "String1","myString")
```

Then you have a one liner to invoke.

Comment: Typo: `coll ax Collection` must be `coll as Collection`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the `Before` argument to fulfill this requirement?

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestProject()
    Dim myStrings As New Collection

    myStrings.Add item:="Text 1"
    myStrings.Add item:="Text 2"
    myStrings.Add item:="Text 3"

    ' Print out the content of collection "myStrings"
    Debug.Print "--- Initial collection content ---"
    PrintCollectionContent myStrings
    ' Or with the "Call" keyword: Call PrintCollectionContent(myStrings)
    Debug.Print "--- End Initial collection content ---"

    ' Now we want to change "Text 2" into "New Text"
    myStrings.Add item:="New Text", Before:=2 ' myStrings will now contain 4 items
    Debug.Print "--- Collection content after adding the new content ---"
    ' Print out the 'in-between' status of collection "myStrings" where we have
    ' both the new string and the string to be replaced still in.
    PrintCollectionContent myStrings
    Debug.Print "--- End Collection content after adding the new content ---"

    myStrings.Remove 3
    ' Print out the final status of collection "myStrings" where the obsolete 
    ' item is removed
    Debug.Print "--- Collection content after removal of the old content ---"
    PrintCollectionContent myStrings
    Debug.Print "--- End Collection content after removal of the old content ---"

End Sub

Private Sub PrintCollectionContent(ByVal myColl As Variant)
    Dim i as Integer

    For i = 1 To myColl.Count()
        Debug.Print myColl.Item(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Shouldn't this do the job?

Comment: +1 because it fulfills the OP's request; but for that, you have to fix: 1) the first two lines in fact are one only, and you left a crazy leftover (Set myStringsRef = myStrings) that was nor declared nor necessary; 2)  PrintCollectionContent (myStringsRef) - or (myStrings) your call - need that OR use Call before, OR remove parenthesis after.

Comment: @MarceloScofano: You're correct in that I've used the "crazy leftover" because at that time I didn't know exactly when to use `Call` or not (with only one param I know now you don't have to use `Call`, very confusing at first).  Therefore, I used that "useless" variable `myStringsRef`.  I also didn't use the `Option Explicit` in my example code, so there was no need to declare that one first.  Being a VBA newbee at that time, I know now that I don't want to work anymore without the `Option Explicit` and I also know now better the way the `Collections` are working...  I edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I said crazy because at first I swore that it fits in the code, so I declared myStringsRef and did a mess! Only after some minutes spent I decided to get rid of it and could see that your answer fits. Thanks for your answer, it convinced me that I do not have to use dictionary for what I need. And for reference for everyone that is passing here and do not understand why Call () vs no(), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4426180/2752308) is an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution where `Coll("String1") = "myString"` ***does*** work.

When you `.Add` an object to a VBA collection, the object itself is added, not its value. This means you can change the object's properties while it is in the collection. I've created a class module which wraps a single variant in a class object, with `.Value` as its default property. Save this to a `.cls` file, then `File > Import File` in the VBA editor.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "clsValue"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private MyValue As Variant
Property Get Value() As Variant
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Value = MyValue
End Property
Property Let Value(v As Variant)
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    MyValue = v
End Property
```

Now this version of your code works the way you had hoped:

```
Private Sub clsValue_test()
Dim Coll As New Collection
Dim myArr()
Dim v As Variant
myArr = Array("String1", "String2", "String3")
For Each v In myArr
    Coll.Add New clsValue, v
    Coll(v) = "NULL"
Next v
Coll("String1") = "myString"    ' it works!
For Each v In myArr
    Debug.Print v, ": "; Coll(v)
Next v
End Sub
```

Produces the result:

```
String1       : myString
String2       : NULL
String3       : NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of [making a function that deletes the collection item by its key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30414678/4299943), is implementing it as a VBA *Property*

```
Public Property Let CollectionValue(coll As Collection, key As String, value As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Remove key
    On Error GoTo 0
    coll.Add value, key
End Property


Public Property Get CollectionValue(coll As Collection, key As String) As String
    CollectionValue = coll(key)
End Property
```

And Used like this

```
'Writing
CollectionValue(coll, "Date") = Now()

'Reading
Debug.Print(CollectionValue(coll, "Date"))
```

By ignoring if key not exists, it can be used to add items as well

Answer (score 0):

just loop the collection and add the new values to a new collection...

```
function prep_new_collection(my_old_data as collection) as collection

dim col_data_prep as new collection

for i = 1 to my_old_data.count

if my_old_data(i)(0)= "whatever" then

  col_data_prep.add array("NULL", my_old_data(i)(1))

else

 col_data_prep.add array(my_old_data(i)(0), my_old_data(i)(1))

end if

next i

 set prep_new_collection = col_data_prep

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue an thought to post my solution here for any one who might need it. my solution was to make a class called
*`EnhancedCollection`* that has an update function.  save this code to a file named *`EnhancedCollection.cls`* and then import into your project.

```
    VERSION 1.0 CLASS
    BEGIN
      MultiUse = -1  'True
    END
    Attribute VB_Name = "EnhancedCollection"
    Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
    Attribute VB_Creatable = False
    Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
    Attribute VB_Exposed = False
    Option Explicit
    
    Private data As New Collection
       
    '=================================ADD
    
    If IsMissing(key) Then
        If IsMissing(before) Then
            If IsMissing(after) Then
                data.Add Value
            Else
                data.Add Value, , , after
            End If
        Else
            data.Add Value, , before
        End If
    ElseIf key = "TEMP_ITEM" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsMissing(before) Then
            If IsMissing(after) Then
                data.Add Value, key
            Else
                data.Add Value, key, , after
            End If
        Else
            data.Add Value, key, before
        End If
    End If
End Sub
'=================================REMOVE

Sub Remove(key As Variant)
    data.Remove key
End Sub

    '=================================COUNT
    
    Function Count() As Integer
        Count = data.Count
    End Function
    '=================================ITEM
    
    Function Item(key As Variant) As Variant
    'This is the default Function of the class
    Attribute Item.VB_Description = "returns the item"
    Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    On Error GoTo OnError
        If VarType(key) = vbString Or VarType(key) = vbInteger Then
            Item = data.Item(key)
        End If
        Exit Function
    OnError:
        Item = Null
    End Function
    '=================================Update
    
    Function Update(key As Variant, Value As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo OnError
        If VarType(key) = vbString Or VarType(key) = vbInteger Then
            data.Add "", "TEMP_ITEM", , key
            data.Remove key
            data.Add Value, key, "TEMP_ITEM"
            data.Remove "TEMP_ITEM"
        End If
        Exit Function
    OnError:
        Update = Null
    End Function
```

And as an added benefit, you can always add more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tcoll()
 Dim c As New Collection
 c.Add Array("1", 2, False)
 c.Add Array("2", 3, False)
 c.Add Array("1", 4, False)
 For Each ci In c:  Debug.Print ci(0), ci(1), ci(2): Next
 If 1 Then
  'ok
  For X = c.Count To 1 Step -1
   Select Case c(X)(0)
   Case "1"
    c.Add Array(c(X)(0), c(X)(1), 1), after:=X
    c.Remove X
   Case "2"
    c.Remove X
   End Select
  Next
 Else
  'Subscript out of range
  For X = 1 To c.Count
   Select Case c(X)(0)
   Case "1"
    c(X)(2) = 1 'no error but collection is not changed
   Case "2"
    c.Remove X
   End Select
  Next
 End If
 For Each ci In c:  Debug.Print ci(0), ci(1), ci(2): Next
 Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```