# VBA instance item not being changed

Tags: vba, excel, class

```
' CDays
Private pZone As New Collection

Public Property Get Zone() As Collection
    Set Zone = pZone
End Property
Public Property Let Zone(Value As Variant)
    For Each element In Value
        pZone.Add element
    Next
End Property
```

and sub has

```
' Main Sub
dy.Zone.item("Zone1")(5) = 0
```

Where dy is an instance
"Zone1" is set as the key for Item1 in below

Structure for dy instance looks as follows
[image]

This does not change the value in Item(5) however. Why?

Comment: It's rather hard to correlate the code you provided to the locals toolwindow screenshot. Can you make an actual [mcve] (emphasis on *complete*) so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Collections don't support what you're trying to do.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541710/how-to-change-value-of-an-item-of-a-collection

Comment: If you want to access items using a string as a key and also to edit the item, you probably want a Scripting dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class which will wrap the items which will be added to `VBA.Collection`. Then it is possible to add/change such items using the collection reference. HTH

> Class Foo

```
Option Explicit

Private m_id As Integer
Private m_value As String

Public Property Get ID() As Variant
    ID = m_id
End Property

Public Property Let ID(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    m_id = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Val() As Variant
    Val = m_value
End Property

Public Property Let Val(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    m_value = vNewValue
End Property
```

> Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
Dim col As VBA.Collection
Set col = New VBA.Collection

Dim f As Foo
Set f = New Foo
f.ID = 1
f.Val = "AAA"

col.Add f, VBA.CStr(f.ID)

Debug.Print col(f.ID).Val

col(f.ID).Val = "BBB"

Debug.Print col(f.ID).Val

End Sub
```

> Output

```
AAA
BBB
```