# Excel vba: Reassign collection member

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Collection` that stores `Date` objects. I want to check if a month of a date object is different from 1 and if so, set it to 1.

```
Sub displayColl()
    Dim globals As Object
    Set globals = getGlobalVariables()

    Dim dates As Collection
    Set dates = getResultDates(globals("MIN_DATE"), globals("MAX_DATE"), False)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To dates.Count
         Debug.Print dates(i)
    Next

    Debug.Print "After"

    For i = 1 To dates.Count
        Debug.Print dates(i)
        dates(i) = DateSerial(year(dates(i)), 1, Day(dates(i)))
    Next
End Sub
```

However, this code doesn't work - I get `Object requered error`. Why is that? What is the right way to do it?

**EDIT:**

- `getResultDates` function isn't important. It simply returns a `Collection` of `Dates`.
- The same goes for `getGlobalVariables` - it returns a dictionary with information from user, including minimum and maximum dates a user wrote.
- The error occurs on line `Set dates(i) = DateSerial(year(dates(i)), 1, Day(dates(i)))`.
- Removing `Set` doesn't accomplish anything.
- I am sure the `dates` `Collection` contains dates.

The debug output:

```
01.01.2014 
01.02.2014 
01.03.2014 
01.04.2014 
01.05.2014 
01.06.2014 
01.07.2014 
01.08.2014 
01.09.2014 
01.10.2014 
01.11.2014 
01.12.2014 
01.01.2015 
01.02.2015 
01.03.2015 
01.04.2015 
01.05.2015 
01.06.2015 
01.07.2015 
01.08.2015 
01.09.2015 
01.10.2015 
01.11.2015 
01.12.2015 
01.01.2016 
01.02.2016 
01.03.2016 
01.04.2016 
01.05.2016 
01.06.2016 
01.07.2016 
01.08.2016 
01.09.2016 
01.10.2016 
01.11.2016 
01.12.2016 
01.01.2017 
After
01.01.2014
```

Comment: Remove the `Set`

Comment: Please can you include the `getResultDates ` and `getGlobalVariables ` functions to make it easier for us to help debugging and trying out your code

Comment: `Set dates = getResultDates(globals("MIN_DATE"), globals("MAX_DATE"), False)` -- are you sure that `dates` isn't `Nothing` after this line?

Comment: @Spangen, See edit. Those function are not relevant.

Comment: @John Coleman I either know what's wrong or not. Scott Craner already wrote lots of suggestions that I checked not to influence the code in any way. I edited the code and question to include debug output that clearly shows the collection does contains relevant data.

Comment: The dates are not true dates but text strings that look like dates.  Try this, instead of `Debug.Print dates(i)` put `Debug.Print Day(dates(i))`.  Your error will now point at the new line.

Comment: @John Coleman Changed that, but it *doesn't influence the result*.

Comment: I'm surprised that `Set` keyword isn't causing an *Object Required* run-time error. Dates aren't objects, they're values - and you don't `Set` a value. FWIW "Removing 'Set' doesn't accomplish anything" sounds rather cocky: using `Set` the way you do **will** cause problems one day or another - might as well learn to use it properly.

Comment: @Mat's Mug How many times do I need to write that adding/removing `Set` doesn't case problems in my code? You are free to create a similar example with dates when Set will cause a problem, but I doubt it, given it's problem free to me already.

Comment: @Ans, your tone is very aggressive towards those people trying to help you. Just sayin'

Comment: Fine then, keep misusing it. The day you come here to ask about an "object required" run-time error, I'll link back to that very comment and say "told ya".

Comment: @Spangen, I do appreciate the help, but I see no point when everyone posts basically the same comment about `Set` keyword.

Comment: @Ans I will say that @Mat'sMug has forgotten more about vba than most of us know.  The issue he is stating is that the `Set` may not be the main problem in this case but it would be if there was not a second error that took precedent.  If you try  `Set t = dates(i)` you will get an error. So you have two issues with that line.  The `Set` issue and another, which I believe the answer below explains.  The `Set` is like a broken leg while having a heart attack.  Once the heart attack is resolved the broken leg will still need to be addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Microsoft's VBA docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx
you can add, delete and retrieve items of a collection. It doesn't suggest you can replace items directly as you could with a Java List for instance.

You could add in the new date and remove the old one.

This is also discussed in 
[How to change value of an item of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541710/how-to-change-value-of-an-item-of-a-collection)