# How to change a VBA collection value via seperate function

Tags: vba, function, collections

I am trying to change some values of a string collection inside a seperate function. As I understood, collections are treated ByRef as default, when using them as function parameter. Unfortunately, I get the following error when running the below code:

> Run-time error '424' Object required

```
Function MyFunc1
   Dim b as Collection: Set b = New Collection
   b.Add "test1"
   b.Add "test2"
   MyFunc2 b
End Function


Private Function MyFunc2(c As Collection)
   c(1) = "hello"
End Function
```

edit:
I found a solution using dictionaries:

```
Private Function MyFunc1()
    Dim b As Collection: Set b = New Collection
    b.Add "test1"
    b.Add "test2"
    Call myFunc2(b)
End Function

Private Function myFunc2(c As Collection)
    c.Remove 1
    c.Add "hello", , 1
End Function
```

Comment: `MyFunc1` should be a sub - not a function.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Items in a collection are read-only.

Comment: I think @JosephC is correct - you could do this with a dictionary though

Comment: JosephC is right. Your error has nothing to do with passing the collection to a function (or sub), you will get the same error when you write `b(1) = "hello"` in `MyFunc1`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541710/how-to-change-value-of-an-item-of-a-collection

Comment: ^^ Pretty close to being  a complete dupe I would say

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Dictionary would be an option, but I found another solution using collections. Please see my edited first post

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this if you are willing to use a dictionary object;

```
Function MyFunc1()

Dim b As New Scripting.Dictionary

   b.Add key:="1", Item:="test1"
   b.Add key:="2", Item:="test2"

   ' Example Call to update function
   Set b = updateDictWithStringValue(b, "1", "hello")

End Function

Public Function updateDictWithStringValue(d As Dictionary, key As String, value As String) As Dictionary

d.Remove key
d.Add value, key
Set updateCollectionWithStringValue = d

End Function
```

you need to include a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime